# Чем заменить string.Empty?

Tags: c#, .net

Чтобы метод InventorySorter работал пришлось каждому элементу массива присвоить string.Empty

Как можно обойтись без этого?

```
public class Inventory
{
    public string[] inventorySlots = new string[9] {string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty };

    public void InventorySorter(string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventorySlots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inventorySlots[i] == string.Empty)
            {
                inventorySlots[i] = name;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если убрать ваши `string.Empty`, то в массиве будут значения по умолчанию: `null`.

Comment: Судя по сути кода, вам следует использовать список вместо массива: `List<string>`.

Comment: Название метода странное: `Sorter`. Вроде он ничего не сортирует, а добавляет.

Comment: А что должен делать этот метод?

Answer (score 2):

Можно доработать условие добавления элемента, например если строка не инициализирована `null` или пуста, то ячейку считать пустой. Здесь неоднозначность какую ячейку инвентрая считать пустой: `null` или `""`? Обе?

Тогда условие проверки должно всегда проверять оба эти условия. Например условие для пустой ячейки можно реализовать так: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inventorySlots[i])) {...}`, а для не пустой вот так `if (inventorySlots[i]?.Length > 0) {...}`.

Однозначности можно конечно достичь тем путем, который вы выбрали, избежать `null` с помощью инициализации массива пустыми строками, в этом случае инициализацию можно упростить вот так:

```csharp
public string[] inventorySlots = Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 9).ToArray();
```

*Посмотрите другие статические методы класса `Enumerable`, там много всего полезного.*

Затем можно оптимизировать сравнение `if (inventorySlots[i].Length == 0)`.

Но я бы на вашем месте в инвентаре хранил бы не строки, а числа `int[]`, и отдельно словарь с элементами инвентаря `Dictionary<int, string>`, где по айдишнику элемента можно получить название элемента и возможно другие его характеристики. Так же, если вы захотите переименовать элемент, или использовать локализации, например интерфейс игры на русском и английском, тогда это не затронет сам инвентарь.

В случае с хранением айдишников `int` - все будет вполне однозначно, `0` - пусто, или `-1` - пусто, просто выберите, что вам больше по душе. К тому же в C# числовые операции сравнения работают значительно быстрее, чем строковые. А еще строка занимает больше памяти. Представьте 1000 инвентарей, хранящих строки, содержащие одни и те же элементы, зачем столько 9000 копий повторяющихся строк хранить в памяти, если можно хранить только по одному экземпляру каждой строки, и добывать ее с помощью числового индекса, хранящегося в инвентаре.

Подумайте над архитектурой того, что вы делаете. Чем раньше вы предусмотрите все возможные проблемы, тем легче будет потом разрабатывать приложение.

Comment: Если что в C# есть интернизация строк, так что проблемы "9000 копий повторяющихся строк хранить в памяти" при желании можно избежать )

Comment: @CrazyElf никто не спорит, можно и кеш реализовать, но словарь это, кмк, более простое и интуитивно понятное решение. Его и в БД при желании достаточно легко положить, он расширяем до `Int32.MaxValue` значений. К тому же, это не обязательно должен быть словарь строк, он может быть словарь экземпляров класса, представляющего игровой айтем со всеми своими прибамбасами.

Comment: Да я по остальным вопросам с вами и не спорил, просто небольшое замечание внёс )

Comment: По поводу хранения айдишников одно маленькое замечание: вместо `0` или `-1` как пустой ячейки я бы сделал `null`, а массив бы стал типа `int?[]`. Как лично мне кажется, с точки зрения работы с инвентарем в коде такой подход более понятен будет

Comment: Либо и вовсе на бизнес-слое делать инвентарь как массив классов ячеек инвенторя, где каждая ячейка имеет булево состояние `inventorySlot.HasItem`. Но это уже немного другая история

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Конечно можно, можно даже и не такое. Я просто подал идею, что в инвентаре не обязательно строки хранить, по реализации - решать автору.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам больше такой код понравится:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public const int inventorySlotsLimit = 9;

    public List<string> inventorySlots = new List<string>();

    public void AddItem(string name)
    {
        if(inventorySlots.Count + 1 > inventorySlotsLimit)
        {
            throw new Exception("Inventory overflow");
        }
        inventorySlots.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Код не проверял, но как-то так

```
public class Inventory
{
    public string[] inventorySlots = new string[9];

    public void InventorySorter(string name) =>
        inventorySlots.Where(x => x == null).ForEach(x => x = name);
}
```

Не очень оптимально по работе, зато красиво :)

Оптимизировать можно в том случае если понадобится, что наврядли в даном случае.

Comment: _наврядли в даном случае_ Судя по названию класса, производительность важна, так как это скорее всего игра.

Comment: только судя по уровню спрашивающего, это вероятнее всего проэкт-тренировка и в релиз никогда не выйдет. А других значительно более медленных мест там будет просто завались и это решение просто особо ни на что не повлияет) Оптимизировать ВСЕ И ВСЮДУ как оптимизация ради оптимизации - это вообще довольно глупая затея. Оптимизировать нужно только по мере надобности.

Comment: Ну тогда хотя-бы тогда `.Where` вместо тернаршины. Только если строка пустая, условие не сработает, надо исправить.

Comment: А вот здесь уже согласен, спасибо)